# How do I respawn all players of a particular player controller in ue4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

**Hey guys,**

As soon as a certain number of players is reached, a random player is selected and the "CatcherPlayerController" is assigned to him. All other players keep the standard PlayerController.

How do I get **all** players **only** with the standard PlayerController and respawn them at different points? The whole thing is for a waiting lobby system in which all players, except the "catcher", have to be respawned as soon as the game starts.

I've tried several approaches but haven't found a solution yet. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over all players and get the player controller, try to cast it to CatcherPlayerController and if it fails you know it's a standard PlayerController. Since it's a once in bluemoon event I would not be worried about performance issues of all the cast you should do but it really depends on the number of players. Let me know more if I misunderstood your problem.